# Help! Should I be concerned about this rust on my wagon?

Tags: car, rust, body, saab, frame

2005 Saab 9-5. Looking underneath the passenger side, is this the subframe I'm looking at?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RpmbwwUWoQlVzvFV7pjfsTGADQ-kJKLq?usp=sharing

New subframe doesn't look to be that expensive if it needs to be done...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I am not really seeing rust in the images ... it looks to me as though everything is covered in oil or grime of some sort? If so, that's pretty good rust prevention measures, though it could be signs of something else.

Comment: Maybe try to punch it or otherwise estimate the remaining thickness.